# Undefined Offset: 2 (lines 22, 28, 29)

Tags: php, mysql

The following code shows an error

> "Undefined offset: 2" on lines 22, 28, and 29

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM CommercialEmails WHERE dripid = 1 AND sent='a'";
if ($resultsd1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql )) {
    $affectedrows = mysqli_num_rows($resultsd1);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($resultsd1)){
        $results = $row[0];
        global $results;
    }
}

$broken = explode(' ', $results);
$hi = 0;
$hello = 0;
a:                                          
/**Line 22 **/ if (substr($broken[$hi], -4) == "com," && $broken[$hi] == "qwert"){

    $hey[$hi] = $broken[$hi];
    $hello++;
}

If(substr($broken[$hi], -4) !== "com,"){  // line 28
    $hey[$hi] = $broken[$hi];             //Line 29 
}
$hi++;
if ($hi == $affectedrows){
    if (!isset($hey)){
        echo "There are no emails";
    } else {
        foreach( $hey as $key => $value){
            echo $value;
        }
        echo $hey;
    }
}else{
   goto a;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Your error checking is working! Have you looked at those to see why they're undefined?

Comment: The line numbers for 22, 28 and 29 are commented in the code

Comment: Why are you globalling `$results`? Just initialize it `$results = '';` before the loop.

Comment: well, it is telling you that `$broken[2]` is undefined. You need to look at both `$broken` and how you are looping over/increment `$hi`.

Comment: Do I see a **GOTO** in that code. First time since 1990. Suggest you do some serious reading on basic coding practices.

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, I do see either! :-)

Comment: you could wrap lines 22 through 30 in `if(isset($broken[$hi])){ ... }`

Comment: And whats the `$hello` var for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but to get your code just working try this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM CommercialEmails WHERE dripid = 1 AND sent='a'";
$results = array();
$hey = array();
if ($resultsd1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql )) {
    $affectedrows = mysqli_num_rows($resultsd1);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($resultsd1)){
        $results[] = $row;
        If(substr($row[0], -4) !== "com,"){ 
           $hey[] = $row[0];              
        }
    }
}

if (count($hey)==0){
    echo "There are no emails";
} else {
    foreach( $hey as  $value){
        echo $value;
    }
    echo $hey;
}
```

As you can see I completely removed many of your variables you don't need them until you can explain your goals.

And I've removed your weird condition `if`:

```
if (substr($broken[$hi], -4) == "com," && $broken[$hi] == "qwert"){

    $hey[$hi] = $broken[$hi];
    $hello++;
}
```

Because there is no such value of `$broken[$hi]` that can be equal `'qwert'` and to have `'com'` as substring inside. So this codition is always false and we can delete it.

Try to explain your goals. Hope I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the $broken array does not have 3 elements (ofset index = 2).

I can not see where that $hi var is being set to 2 but it is somewhere in code you have not shown I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `global $results;` inside the while loop, before the while loop starts just declare $results as an empty array `$results = array();`

Then after the while loop ends do `print_r($results);` to see if it has the contents you expect.